# GraphDB Docker Container Fails to Run: adoptopenjdk/openjdk12:alpine

Tags: graphdb

When using the standard DockerFile available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-docker/master/Dockerfile), GraphDB fails to start with the following output:

```
Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME
```

Looking into it, the DockerFile uses `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine` which was recently updated to Alpine 3.14.

If I switch to an older Docker image (or use `adoptopenjdk/openjdk12:alpine`) then GraphDB starts without a problem.

How can I fix this while still using the latest version of `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine`?

Below is the DockerFile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine

# Build time arguments
ARG version=9.1.1
ARG edition=ee

ENV GRAPHDB_PARENT_DIR=/opt/graphdb
ENV GRAPHDB_HOME=${GRAPHDB_PARENT_DIR}/home

ENV GRAPHDB_INSTALL_DIR=${GRAPHDB_PARENT_DIR}/dist

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apk add --no-cache bash curl util-linux procps net-tools busybox-extras wget less && \
    curl -fsSL "http://maven.ontotext.com/content/groups/all-onto/com/ontotext/graphdb/graphdb-${edition}/${version}/graphdb-${edition}-${version}-dist.zip" > \
    graphdb-${edition}-${version}.zip && \
    bash -c 'md5sum -c - <<<"$(curl -fsSL http://maven.ontotext.com/content/groups/all-onto/com/ontotext/graphdb/graphdb-${edition}/${version}/graphdb-${edition}-${version}-dist.zip.md5)  graphdb-${edition}-${version}.zip"' && \
    mkdir -p ${GRAPHDB_PARENT_DIR} && \
    cd ${GRAPHDB_PARENT_DIR} && \
    unzip /tmp/graphdb-${edition}-${version}.zip && \
    rm /tmp/graphdb-${edition}-${version}.zip && \
    mv graphdb-${edition}-${version} dist && \
    mkdir -p ${GRAPHDB_HOME}

ENV PATH=${GRAPHDB_INSTALL_DIR}/bin:$PATH

CMD ["-Dgraphdb.home=/opt/graphdb/home"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/graphdb/dist/bin/graphdb"]

EXPOSE 7200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from an update in the base image. From a few weeks adopt switched to alpine 3.14 which has some issues with older container runtime (runc). The issue can be seen in the release notes: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0

Updating your Docker will fix the issue. However, if you don't wish to update your Docker, there's a workaround.

Some additional info:
The cause of the issue is that for some reason containers running in older docker versions and alpine 3.14 seem to have issues with the test flag "-x" so an if [ -x /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java ] returns false, although java is there and is executable.

You can workaround this for now by

1. Pull the GraphDB distribution
2. Unzip it
3. Open "setvars.in.sh" in the bin folder
4. Find and remove the if block around line 32

> if [ ! -x "$JAVA" ]; then
> echo "Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME"
> exit 1
> fi

5. Zip it again and provide it in the Dockerfile without pulling it from maven.ontotext.com

Passing it to the Dockerfile is done with 'ADD'
You can check the GraphDB free version's Dockerfile for a reference on how to pass the zip file to the Dockerfile https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-docker/blob/master/free-edition/Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looks like Ubuntu 21.04 doesn't have the updated Docker packages needed to avoid this issue. It also looks like some services like CircleCI don't run the latest packages since they fail to run as well.

For now, I'll use `adoptopenjdk/openjdk12:alpine` since that resolves the issue. Are there any potential issues with using OpenJDK12 instead of OpenJDK11?

Comment: Should be fine. I've also tried using adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.10_9-alpine which is using older alpine base image and is working fine